# How to use shap_value explainer for a dataset where PCA has been applied

Tags: python, data-science, shap

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
df_2d = pca.fit_transform(df)

clusterer = hdbscan.HDBSCAN(min_cluster_size=1000)
clusterer.fit(df_2d)

clf = LGBMClassifier()
clf.fit(df_2d, clusterer.labels_) ###

explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(clf)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(df_2d) ###
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, df_2d, plot_type="bar", plot_size=(15, 10)) ###
```

This is my code. It runs perfectly, but it Returns a summary plot with "Feature 1" and "Feature 2". This totally makes sense, because I gave it a dataset which only consists of 2 columns.
But my questions, how could I make it explain the decisions of my decision tree based on the original data?

I have tried this Code, and it worked without error, but I am not sure if I am using it correctly.
(The difference is that I have changed all the df_2d to the original df in the classifier and also in shap)

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
df_2d = pca.fit_transform(df)

clusterer = hdbscan.HDBSCAN(min_cluster_size=1000)
clusterer.fit(df_2d)

clf = LGBMClassifier()
clf.fit(df, clusterer.labels_) ###

explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(clf)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(df) ###
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, df, plot_type="bar", plot_size=(15, 10)) ###
```

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: You could 1) do the interpretation on the PC variables or 2) revert to the original variables. Which one do you prefer?

Comment: 1st is correct. As for the second your intention is not clear. SHAP starts with the data you feed to model, regardless the way you preprocess the data. Theoretically you can feed any data as soon as data shape is the same, but it's not clear how you would interpret it.

Comment: If you want explanation on the original data, do not do the PCA.

Comment: Could we have the data two? perhaps an example / sample for a common dataset?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't give you sample data.
My experience was that I had significantly less outliers when I applied the clustering algorithm to the dataset with PCA. I save these predicted cluster labels and then I apply a decision tree to "explain" how these clusters were chosen based on the original dataset.

Comment: @RafaelValero I would like to do your 2) Point, which is to revert the values back to the original variables. But I thought that if I use the original "unmodified" dataset, then its the same isn't it?

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, and thank you very much for your help!

Comment: If you place and example including data, we could work in the same particular case.

Comment: @szucsaaron did you found any solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use KernelExplainer class which is a model agnostic method.

```
# create pipeline
blackbox_model = Pipeline([('scaler', scaler), ('pca', pca), ('clf', clf)])

# fit model
blackbox_model.fit(X_train, Y_train)


# load JS vis in the notebook
shap.initjs() 

# initiate explainer with pipeline function
explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(blackbox_model.predict_proba, X_train)

# get shapley values for one instance
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test.iloc[0,:])

# plot
shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value[1], shap_values[1], X_test.iloc[0,:])
```

more details here : https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_notebooks/tabular_examples/model_agnostic/Iris%20classification%20with%20scikit-learn.html 
https://shap-lrjball.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/shap.KernelExplainer.html